# THREE.js, BufferGeometry, array.length / itemSize != numItems?

Tags: three.js, webgl

Take a look at the example http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_particles.html

The way the positions buffer is setup is as follows:

```
            var particles = 500000;

            var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
            geometry.attributes = {

                position: {
                    itemSize: 3,
                    array: new Float32Array( particles * 3 ),
                    numItems: particles * 3
                },
```

Should it not always be the case that, if T = geometry.attributes.position, then T.array.length / T.itemSize === T.numItems? If the array has a length of L slots, and each item occupies K slots, it would stand to reason there are L / K items. Yet it seems the example sattes the array has L items? L items would occupy L * K slots :s

I hit this issue with positions as well, and only the first 1/3rd of my vertices were being rendered, because I used the number of vertices as numItems, and itemSize = 3, with a Float32Array of length numItems * itemSize.

What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not misunderstanding anything. The nomenclature could be improved.

Think of it this way:

```
itemSize = (number of components) / vertex

numItems = (number of components)
         = (number of vertices) * itemSize
```

Think of `numItems` as the number of items in the array sent to the GPU.

three.js r.57

Comment: Wouldn't .numItems always be === array.length, then? (So redundant)

Comment: It is a little confusing. Just follow the pattern in the examples.